# Python showing in Windows start menu after uninstalling

Tags: python

I decided that now is as good a time as any to learn Python, so I went to download the latest version 3.9.0. After downloading it, I used the Windows search bar to find that 3.8 was already installed (from a previous attempt at learning Python).

I clicked on 3.8 where it prompted "Modify, Repair, Uninstall". After uninstalling, it's unfortunately still there. The files are nowhere to be found, and I can't interact with them. This is what I see:

[image]

I have tried logging out, restarting, uninstalling 3.9 (so there are no current versions of python), and restarting Cortana in task manager. An old post on Microsoft recommended renaming this file: `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.Windows.Cortana_cw5n1h2txyewy` on reboot, but I don't believe this file exists anymore. I would have just ignored it, but it seems to conflict with 3.9.

Answer (score 1):

I have had this same problem. I cannot get version 3.8 to get off the start window, however, I have resolved the conflict. I first, after uninstalling 3.8 normally, I found the leftover files (the manual) in the `C:\Users\CHfar\AppData\Local\Programs\Python` pathway. I deleted all the 3.8 files. I also uninstalled python 3.9.1.

After starting the install process again, I made sure to click add python 3.9 to PATH.

[image]

To check to see if everything was correct I typed in 'env' into the search at the windows start button and clicked on edit environment variables for your account. I went to Path and clicked Edit. Make sure the python pathways are at the top.

[image]

[image]

In the command prompt, I typed in `C:\...>python --version`

to see if it was installed correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The question was from 2 years ago, but hopefully this can help everyone else with the same problem. You can remove the folders and items from here: C:\Users"your_account_name"\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\